# Duplicate lines containing a string with edits

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I need to find a way to duplicate lines in a file containing a string with small edits. The dupe would have to show up above the original line. Would `sed` or `awk` be my best bet?

Ideally replacing `puppies` with `bunnies` in the new line and `I` with `You`.

For example:

- Input file:

  ```
  I have puppies cute 
  I have two kitties
  I have three puppies cute
  I have four kitties
  ```
- The result would need to be:

  ```
  You have bunnies cute
  I have puppies cute
  I have two kitties
  You have three bunnies cute 
  I have three puppies cute
  I have four kitties
  ```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that in order to help you, you would need to specify the conditions further. How should the program decide which lines do duplicate - all those where a word starts with `-`, or simply those were a `-` is in any place (not necessarily word start)? How is the "modified" result generated (what to replace how)? Also, please include any attempts you already made, and indicate where you ran into problems, so that contributors don't suggest solutions you already know won't work. Ideally, include "border cases" in the example.

Comment: Every answer so far makes assumptions about what your question means since your requirements aren't clear and would fail given slightly different input.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'function prnt() { print edit ORS hold; hold=edit="" }
     hold            { prnt() }
     /puppies/       { hold=$0; $1="you"; gsub("puppies", "bunnies"); edit=$0; next }
END{ if(hold) prnt() }1' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`, and assuming that the trigger is the substring `cute` at the end of the line:

```bsh
sed '/cute[[:blank:]]*$/ { h; s/^I/You/; s/[[:alpha:]]* cute/bunnies cute/; G; }' file
```

The `[[:blank:]]*` in the pattern allows for trailing spaces or tabs at the end of the line (the first line has a trailing space in the question).

This would produce the text

```
You have bunnies cute
I have puppies cute
I have two kitties
You have three bunnies cute
I have three puppies cute
I have four kitties
```

The `h` command saves a copy of the current line in the "hold space".  The first `s///` command changes the `I` at the start of the line to `You` while the second changes whatever word precedes `cute` with `bunnies`. The `G` command finally appends the original line from the hold space to the end of current (modified) line, with a newline character in-between.

---

Variant:

```bsh
sed '/[[:alpha:]]* \(cute[[:blank:]]*\)$/ { h; s//bunnies \1/; s/^I/You/; G; }' file
```

This makes use of the fact that if you leave the regular expression empty in the `s///` command, the most recent regular expression is used.

---

Variant which is triggered by the `puppies` string rather than by `cute`.  This makes it slightly shorter:

```bsh
sed '/puppies/ { h; s//bunnies/; s/^I/You/; G; }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed 'h; s/puppies/bunnies/g; T; s/I/You/; G' < your-file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the **sed** editor :

```
sed -e '
  h;/puppies/G
  s//bunnies/
  /\n/s/^I/You/
' file
```

---

Alternatively with **awk**

```
awk '{h=$0}
  sub(/puppies/, "bunnies") {
    sub(/^I/, "You")
    $0 = $0 ORS h
  };1
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

`gnu sed` with `branches`:

```
sed '
s/puppies/&/g; tfind
n
:find 
    h
    s/puppies/bunnies/g
    s/^I/You/
    G
'
```

`gawk` :

```
awk '$0~/puppies/ {

 original=$0
 sub(/puppies/, "bunnies")
 sub(/^I/, "You")
 print $0, original
 next
} 
{ print }
'
```